# Configuring web.config to send emails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, azure, web-config

I'm about to deploy my first ASP.NET website to Azure:
There is a contact form in my website with 4 text boxes (email, name, subject and body) and send button. I use this configuration to send emails:

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Mohamed &lt;name@outlook.com&gt;">
        <network host="Smtp.live.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="name@outlook.com" password="mypassword"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And this is the handler for the send button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Message.txt");
            string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

            mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", TextBoxName.Text);
            mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", TextBoxEmail.Text);
            mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Subject##", TextBoxSubject.Text);
            mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Body##", TextBoxBody.Text);
            MailMessage visitorMessage = new MailMessage();
            visitorMessage.Subject = "New Message: " + TextBoxSubject.Text;
            visitorMessage.Body = mailBody;

            visitorMessage.From = new MailAddress(TextBoxEmail.Text, TextBoxName.Text);
            visitorMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("name@outlook.com", "Mohamed"));
            visitorMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(TextBoxEmail.Text));
            SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            mySmtpClient.Send(visitorMessage);
            LabelIRespond.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

I use these settings for the IIS server, obviously it's not working with production server.
Please tell me what changes should I make to enable this function?

**EDIT**
when I send message from the form, The process terminates, and I receive a privacy warning to my email.

Comment: What *does* the production server do? Do you see an exception? Is a log message written? What's different about the environment it *does* work in and your production environment? "it's not working" doesn't really describe the issue.

Comment: The process doesn't complete and I receive an email with subject "Microsoft account unusual sign-in activity‏"

Comment: shouldn't you be using an SMTP server to send emails and not your personal?  Azure sending an email probably throws out a red flag, whereas locally you're probably "white listed" or something similar for your testing purposes.

Comment: I use it to enable visitors sending me emails, so I use my personal email as "from" and "to" email.

Comment: from http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure Sending email directly from a cloud like Windows Azure presents further challenges, because you don’t have a dedicated IP address, and it’s quite likely that spammers will use Windows Azure (if they haven’t already) to send truckloads of spam. Once that happens, spam blacklists will quickly flag the IP range of Windows Azure data centers as sources of spam. That means your legitimate email will stop getting through.

Comment: If you haven't got a public mail server I'd recommend using SendGrid - the free package that comes with an Azure subscription is excellent. Might be overkill for one contact form, but thought I'd mention it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog post on sending emails using windows azure:

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure

TLDR - don't use your personal email on a cloud host to send emails, it's likely these services black list cloud host IP address ranges to help prevent spam.  Get a legit SMTP server set up either on prem, in the cloud, or use a third party service as pointed out in the post linked.